# Need assistance with a google sheets formula (incrementing issue)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, auto-increment

I'm using this formula to ref from one google sheet to another.
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HKmUMM4vLvNt9Z20Yc_VyrDx25MxlDQlJjTAXtHl-p4/edit#gid=397776635", "012!D1")

I need the part that says 012 to increment, but I need the D1 part to stay the same.
Any suggestions?

TIA

=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HKmUMM4vLvNt9Z20Yc_VyrDx25MxlDQlJjTAXtHl-p4/edit#gid=397776635", "012!D1")

Answer (score 0):

To import the same range from many tabs in a source spreadsheet, and flatten those ranges into one row each, use `reduce()`, `flatten()` and `transpose()`, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  sheetNames, rangeA1, header, 
  reduce( 
    header, sheetNames, 
    lambda( 
      result, sheetName, 
      { 
        result; 
        iferror( 
          transpose( flatten( 
            importrange( 
              "1HKmUMM4vLvNt9Z20Yc_VyrDx25MxlDQlJjTAXtHl-p4", 
              sheetName & "!" & rangeA1 
            ) 
          ) ), 
          header 
        ) 
      } 
    ) 
  )
)( 
  { "001", "002", "003" }, 
  "D4:D8", 
  { "Dress name 1", "Amour Code", "Size", "Colour", "Price" } 
)
```

You can replace `{ "001", "002", "003" }` with another expression that produces an array of sheet names. The number of values in `header` must match the number of columns in `rangeA1`.

Comment: Thank you - the D part isn't the issue, that is staying the same, but I need the 012 to automatically move to the next number 013 then 014 in the formula in the next row (hope that makes sense :)

Comment: That is exactly what the formula shown above does.

Answer (score 0):

Is "012" the name of the sheet?
You can do something like this:

```
=BYROW(INDEX(text(sequence(20,1,12,1),"000")),LAMBDA(each,Importrange("1HKmUMM4vLvNt9Z20Yc_VyrDx25MxlDQlJjTAXtHl-p4",each&"!D1")))
```

Change BYROW with BYCOL if you want it horizontally. Change 20 with the amount of sheets you need to grab and 12 to your first sheet (I've put 12 because it was your example).

PS: It works when you only import one cell

Comment: Thank you. 012 is the name of a sheet, then 013 is the next sheet etc...it starts from 001 and goes up to 100 so I need each row to reflect the information from each sheet. (various columns)

Comment: Then Try =BYCOL(INDEX(text(sequence(89,1,12,1),"000")),LAMBDA(each,Importrange("1HKmUMM4vLvNt9Z20Yc_VyrDx25MxlDQlJjTAXtHl-p4",each&"!D1")))

Answer (score 0):

try this and drag down the formula:

`=IFERROR(LAMBDA(tab,Importrange("1HKmUMM4vLvNt9Z20Yc_VyrDx25MxlDQlJjTAXtHl-p4",tab&"!D1"))(text(row(A1),"000")),(text(row(A1),"000"))&" :NO TAB FOUND")`

-

[image]